How to parse the dimensional shapes of a tensor string?
Here is a string representation of one tensor/matrix, which denotes its print results. For instance, string s = "[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]" represents the tensor is:
[
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
    ]
]

and we know it has three dimensions. From the outside to the inside, the first dimension has one element. The second dimension has two elements. The third dimension has three elements. As a result, we know the shape is [1,2,3].
So, how to generally parse the dimensional shape without using library function. The interface could be:
std::vector<int> parse_shape_from_tensor_string(std::string s){

}

It is more like a LeetCode problem but we did not find similar description. Thanks for your help :)

It's not dimension, it's rank. The tensor has rank 3 with dimension 1 x 2 x 3.

"how to generally parse the dimensional shape" the same way you parse arithmetic expressions with parentheses, which should be covered in algorithm textbooks. What is your attempt?

It is more like a LeetCode problem but we did not find similar description: it seems to be the second time you post the same question, and you did the same mistake to mention LeetCode. Please note that LeetCode and other competitive programming sites are hated by most StackOverflow seniors members. Your question will loose lots of interest to others while they realize that it comes from a competitive programming site.

It is generally recommended that you edit your previous question instead of deleting it and re-posting.

Assuming your inputs are all valid strings, I have the following code:
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> g_result;

int RecrusiveParser(vector<string> s, int& i, int layer) {
    int res = 0;
    while (i < s.size()) {
        if (s[i] == "[") {
            i = i + 1;
            int temp = RecrusiveParser(s, i, layer + 1);
            res++;
            g_result[layer] = temp;
        }
        else if (s[i] == "]") {
            i++;
            return res;
        }
        else {
            if (g_result.size() == 0)
                g_result.resize(layer);
            while (s[i] != "[" && s[i] != "]") {
                i += 1;
                res++;
            }
            i += 1;
            return res;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
// "[[2,2],[2,2]]"
void Parser(vector<string> s) {
    g_result.clear();
    int i = 0;
    RecrusiveParser(s, i, 0);
}

vector<string> tokenize(string s) {
    vector<string> res;
    string temp = "";
    for (char i : s) {
        if (i == ',' || i == '[' || i == ']') {
            if (temp.size() > 0) {
                res.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
            }
            if (i != ',') {
                string temp(1, i);
                res.push_back(temp);
            }
            
        }
        else {
            temp += i;
        }
        
    }
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
void printVect(vector<T> result) {
    for (T i : result) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    auto v = tokenize("[[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]],[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]]]");// out 2,3,2
    printVect(v);
    Parser(v);
    printVect(g_result);

    v = tokenize("[[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]],[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]],[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]]]");// out 3,3,2
    printVect(v);
    Parser(v);
    printVect(g_result);

    v = tokenize("[1,2,3,4]");// out 4
    printVect(v);
    Parser(v);
    printVect(g_result);
}

In the first step of obtaining the string, I decompose it into tokens, using "," and "[","]" as delimiters, among which "[","]" should be retained.
vector<string> tokenize(string s) {
    vector<string> res;
    string temp = "";
    for (char i : s) {
        if (i == ',' || i == '[' || i == ']') {
            if (temp.size() > 0) {
                res.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
            }
            if (i != ',') {
                // "[","]" should be retained
                string temp(1, i);
                res.push_back(temp);
            }
            
        }
        else {
            // Numbers containing multiple digits
            temp += i;
        }   
    }
    return res;
}

Next, the token sequence is processed recursively.
int RecrusiveParser(vector<string> s, int& i, int layer) {
    int res = 0;
    while (i < s.size()) {
        if (s[i] == "[") {
            i = i + 1;
            int temp = RecrusiveParser(s, i, layer + 1);
            res++;
            g_result[layer] = temp;
        }
        else if (s[i] == "]") {
            i++;
            return res;
        }
        else {
            if (g_result.size() == 0)
                g_result.resize(layer);
            while (s[i] != "[" && s[i] != "]") {
                i += 1;
                res++;
            }
            i += 1;
            return res;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}

Every time we encounter '[', we recurse downward, and every time we encounter ']' we return.
Here, res is the dimension of each layer.
When it is the innermost layer, res is the among of numbers, for example, "[[[2,22],[2,2],[111,2]],[[2,22],[2,2] ,[111,2]]]" , the innermost layer is [2,22], res = 2.
When it is not the innermost level, the res of the current layer is the number of times of downward recursion from the current layer.For example, for "[, [, 2, 22, ], [,2,2,],[,111,2],]", we recurse downward once each from i=1, i=5, i=9, So the res of the current level is 3

When you are going to show a C++ example : Do NOT include "C" header files, pass vector<string> s by (const) reference. Do NOT use "magic" return values (but either throw an exception or return a std::optional). And stop using using namespace std; . Side note if you pass your string by const reference you can also return a std::vector<std::string_view> instead.

Using a global like g_result is also not recommeded.
